# Mount CIFS - permission denied

Tags: linux, mount, nas, cifs

I try to mount a folder shared by Windows 10. The Win10 client is part of a corporate domain. The user login is also part of the domain (local users are forbidden by domain policy). Using `smbclient` , the folder can be accessed without problem:

```
user@NAS:~$ smbclient //server/folder -A /logincred

Domain=[DOMAIN] OS=[] Server=[]
smb: \>
```

The login credentials file has the following format:

```
username=USER
password=********
domain=DOMAIN
```

When trying to mount the same folder, using the same credentials file I get a permission error:

```
fd_admin@FDNAS:~$sudo mount -t cifs //server/folder /mnt/smbshare -o vers=3.0,credentials=/.logincred --verbose
Password:
domain=DOMAIN
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=[IP],unc=\\server\folder,vers=3.0,user=USER,,domain=DOMAIN,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

The kernel log is not giving more information:

```
NAS kernel: [2513666.498825] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
NAS kernel: [2513666.504632] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

user, domain and password are correctly displayed in the mount.cifs printout. I also tried the sec parameter with all posibilities. SMB v1 is blocked on the server.

- Kernel Version - 3.10.105
- mount.cifs version: 5.5

Any ideas why smbclient works but mounting fails?

[UPDATE]

SMBclient version : 4.4.16

I don't know if the server requires SMB encrytion. How can I find out if it does?

Here is the requested verbose printout. `-d auth:7` does not work for me so I did the -d 7 as below:

```
admin@NAS:~$ smbclient //server/folder -d 7 -A /logincred
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Cannot opendir for custom conf
Processing section "[global]"
Can't find include file /var/tmp/nginx/smb.netbios.aliases.conf
/etc/samba/smb.reserved.conf not found
Cannot opendir for custom conf
find syno address:
        [0]: XXX.YYY.196.21
        [1]: VVV.ZZZ.126.36
        [2]: VVV.ZZZ.3.29
        [3]: VVV.ZZZ.19.246
added interface ovs_eth0 ip=XXX.YYY.196.21 bcast=XXX.YYY.199.255 netmask=255.255.252.0
added interface ovs_eth2 ip=VVV.ZZZ.3.29 bcast=VVV.ZZZ.255.255 netmask=255.255.0.0
added interface ovs_eth3 ip=VVV.ZZZ.19.246 bcast=VVV.ZZZ.255.255 netmask=255.255.0.0
added interface ovs_eth1 ip=VVV.ZZZ.126.36 bcast=VVV.ZZZ.255.255 netmask=255.255.0.0
Client started (version 4.4.16).
tdb(/run/samba/gencache.tdb): tdb_open_ex: could not open file /run/samba/gencache.tdb: Permission denied
resolve_hosts: Attempting host lookup for name SERVER<0x20>
Connecting to XXX.YYY.200.189 at port 445
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=120)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.30
got OID=1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
got OID=1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
got OID=1.2.840.113554.1.2.2.3
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=not_defined_in_RFC4178@please_ignore
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
gensec_update [NT_STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED]
Got challenge flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62898215
NTLMSSP: Set final flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
gensec_update [NT_STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED]
NTLMSSP Sign/Seal - Initialising with flags:
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62088215
gensec_update [NT_STATUS_OK]
Domain=[DOMAIN] OS=[] Server=[]
smb: \>
```

Comment: What 'smbclient' version are you using? Could you post the `smbclient -d auth:7` log of a connection attempt? Do you know whether the server is configured to require SMB encryption?

Comment: @user1686 thanks for the feedback, I added the requested information

Answer (score 0):

It took quite some time, but it turned out that this behavior is linked to the fact that `//server` is infact a DFS-Namespace.
Mount-CIFS obviously cannot handle this.

The solution is to only mount "folders with targets" as described in [this Microsoft document](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-server/storage/dfs-namespaces/dfs-overview), and then use the actual folder targets directly. In Windows they can be viewed in the folder properties at "DFS". Just select an active one from the list.